# Rails 3.1 HAML escaping too much on a an `:escaped` chunk, how to control it so that it only escapes ampersands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a chunk of code provided by Wistia to embed videos into a page.  This source is embedable raw html and they include some ampersands in it directly.  Of course my w3c validator yells at me all day long and with these in it I'm getting hundreds of errors like:
`& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)`

My view is in HAML so I'm assuming that I needed to escape the sequence, which I happily did with:

```
:escape
  <object width="...
```

Upon doing this the video no longer loads as it has escaped the entire string with `&lt;object width=&quot; ... etc.`

**How would one properly escape such sequences programmatically vs manually altering the inserted string each time a new update is made in Rails 3.1 with HAML?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to put your HTML into its own partial, then render it into a string and do a `String#gsub` on it.

Put your Wistia HTML into a partial called something like **app/views/shared/_wistia.html**

Then create a helper that looks like:

```
def embed_video(partial)
  html = render_to_string(:partial => "shared/#{partial}")
  html.gsub '&', '&amp;'
end
```

And in your HAML, just put `= embed_video 'wistia'` wherever you want the video to be inserted.

Comment: It just occurred to me that render_to_string is part of ActionController::Base and may not be callable from a helper.  If that's the case, you might just need to move that code into a controller and store the result in an instance variable like `@video = html.gsub('&', '&amp;')`